# Finding total combination conditionally

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 4 points: 1,2,3,4

I have then 3 objects A, B and C.

A can go only into 1 or 2

B can go into any of 1,2,3

C can go into all 1,2,3,4

How many possible combinations of objects we can have on those 4 points.

Note: each point can take any number of objects.

When manually done, I get 18 different combinations. But can you help me find a general equation for this?

Comment: Can a point be without objects? If so, you have $2\times 3\times 4$ possibilities. Just write the 3 tuples of where do you put (A,B,C) and so multiply possibilities for A, possibilities for B and possibilities for C.

Comment: This is what I have done but it's 24 then. But when I am doing manually I am only getting 18 combinations. Yes, a point can be without objects

Comment: Yes, it is 24 then.

Comment: @Phicar Yes, it was my mistake with the manual solution